# Steam API to get game info

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steambot, steam-condenser

how will I use steam API to get the info on a game if they search a game name in my website
, I'm new to using API's please help!!
example : I need to get the games minimum requirement in my website from steam

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Take a look at Steam's Web API Documentation:**
https://steamcommunity.com/dev

That should guide you through all the process. Make sure you read everything carefully so you won't miss anything!

**These might help you:**

- All Apps API: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?key=STEAMKEY&format=json

Replace `STEAMKEY` in the url to your desired Steam Key.

- App details API: [http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids={APP_ID}](http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=%7BAPP_ID%7D)

Replace `App_ID` in the url to your desired Application/Game ID.

Comment: App details API no longer works.

Comment: Yes it does, appdetails still works.